# Pasar variables de JavaScript entre páginas

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Tengo un formulario el cual por medio de peticiones a un servidor externo obtengo unos datos en JSON, estos datos los almaceno en variables, pero ¿cómo hago para pasar esas variables en un documento HTML y usarlas en ese documento? ¿Podríais darme algún sencillo ejemplo? Lo que encuentro por el buscador parece muy rebuscado.

Answer (score 6):

En HTML5 puedes hacer uso de `localStorage`(que es algo parecido a utilizar cookies) para lograr lo que deseas.

Ejemplo página 1:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var getInput = prompt("Escribe algo: ");
    localStorage.setItem("nombre_variable",getInput);
}
```

Ejemplo página 2:

```
window.onload = alert(localStorage.getItem("nombre_variable"));
```